# TypeError: 'set' type is unordered when creating pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `clinical info` dataframe. When in dictionary form, it looks like this:

```
clinical_dict = clinical_info[1:10].to_dict()

{'days_to_death': {'TCGA-02-0003-01A': 144.0,
  'TCGA-02-0004-01A': 345.0,
  'TCGA-02-0006-01B': 558.0,
  'TCGA-02-0007-01A': 705.0,
  'TCGA-02-0009-01A': 322.0,
  'TCGA-02-0010-01A': 1077.0,
  'TCGA-02-0011-01B': 630.0,
  'TCGA-02-0014-01A': 2512.0,
  'TCGA-02-0015-01A': 627.0},
 'vital_status': {'TCGA-02-0003-01A': 'dead',
  'TCGA-02-0004-01A': 'dead',
  'TCGA-02-0006-01B': 'dead',
  'TCGA-02-0007-01A': 'dead',
  'TCGA-02-0009-01A': 'dead',
  'TCGA-02-0010-01A': 'dead',
  'TCGA-02-0011-01B': 'dead',
  'TCGA-02-0014-01A': 'dead',
  'TCGA-02-0015-01A': 'dead'},
 'age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': {'TCGA-02-0003-01A': 50,
  'TCGA-02-0004-01A': 59,
  'TCGA-02-0006-01B': 56,
  'TCGA-02-0007-01A': 40,
  'TCGA-02-0009-01A': 61,
  'TCGA-02-0010-01A': 20,
  'TCGA-02-0011-01B': 18,
  'TCGA-02-0014-01A': 25,
  'TCGA-02-0015-01A': 50},
 'gender': {'TCGA-02-0003-01A': 'male',
  'TCGA-02-0004-01A': 'male',
  'TCGA-02-0006-01B': 'female',
  'TCGA-02-0007-01A': 'female',
  'TCGA-02-0009-01A': 'female',
  'TCGA-02-0010-01A': 'female',
  'TCGA-02-0011-01B': 'female',
  'TCGA-02-0014-01A': 'male',
  'TCGA-02-0015-01A': 'male'},
 'karnofsky_performance_score': {'TCGA-02-0003-01A': 100.0,
  'TCGA-02-0004-01A': 80.0,
  'TCGA-02-0006-01B': 80.0,
  'TCGA-02-0007-01A': 80.0,
  'TCGA-02-0009-01A': 80.0,
  'TCGA-02-0010-01A': 80.0,
  'TCGA-02-0011-01B': 80.0,
  'TCGA-02-0014-01A': 100.0,
  'TCGA-02-0015-01A': 80.0},
 'patient.gender': {'TCGA-02-0003-01A': 0,
  'TCGA-02-0004-01A': 0,
  'TCGA-02-0006-01B': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0007-01A': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0009-01A': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0010-01A': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0011-01B': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0014-01A': 0,
  'TCGA-02-0015-01A': 0},
 'patient.vital_status': {'TCGA-02-0003-01A': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0004-01A': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0006-01B': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0007-01A': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0009-01A': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0010-01A': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0011-01B': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0014-01A': 1,
  'TCGA-02-0015-01A': 1},
 'survival': {'TCGA-02-0003-01A': 'non-lts',
  'TCGA-02-0004-01A': 'non-lts',
  'TCGA-02-0006-01B': 'non-lts',
  'TCGA-02-0007-01A': 'non-lts',
  'TCGA-02-0009-01A': 'non-lts',
  'TCGA-02-0010-01A': 'lts',
  'TCGA-02-0011-01B': 'non-lts',
  'TCGA-02-0014-01A': 'lts',
  'TCGA-02-0015-01A': 'non-lts'}}
```

I want to create a `phenotype_label` dataframe that comprises of three lines:

[image]

The first line of a CLS file contains numbers indicating the number of samples and number of classes. The number of samples should correspond to the number of samples in the `clinical_info` dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

phenotype_label = pd.DataFrame()

num_samples = len(clinical_info)
num_classes = clinical_info['survival'].value_counts().count()
val_1 = {num_samples, " ",num_classes, " ",1}
row_1 = pd.Series(val_1)
phenotype_label = phenotype_label.append(row_1)
```

The second line in a CLS file contains a user-visible name for each class. These are the class names that appear in analysis reports. The line should begin with a pound sign (#) followed by a space.

```
class_1 = list(set(list(clinical_info['survival'])))[0]
class_2 = list(set(list(clinical_info['survival'])))[1]
val_2 = {"#", " ", class_1, " ", class_2}
row_2 = pd.Series(val_2)
```

The third line contains a class label for each sample. The class label can be the class name, a number, or a text string. The first label used is assigned to the first class named on the second line; the second unique label is assigned to the second class named; and so on. The number of class labels specified on this line should be the same as the number of samples specified in the first line. The number of unique class labels specified on this line should be the same as the number of classes specified in the first line.

```
val_3 = clinical_info["survival"].to_list()

# Append rows to dataframe
phenotype_label = phenotype_label.append(row_1, row_2, row_3)
phenotype_label.to_csv("phenotype_labels.cls", sep="\t")
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3488eece17aa> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 num_classes = clinical_info['survival'].value_counts().count()
      6 val_1 = {num_samples, " ",num_classes, " ",1}
----> 7 row_1 = pd.Series(val_1)
      8 phenotype_label = phenotype_label.append(row_1)
      9 

/shared-libs/python3.10/py/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    334                 pass
    335             elif isinstance(data, (set, frozenset)):
--> 336                 raise TypeError(f"'{type(data).__name__}' type is unordered")
    337             else:
    338                 data = com.maybe_iterable_to_list(data)

TypeError: 'set' type is unordered
```

Expected output:

|  |
| --- |
| 10 2 1 |
| # non-lts lts |
| non-lts non-lts non-lts non-lts lts non-lts lts non-lts lts |

Answer (score 0):

Sets are unordered in python - you cannot create a pandas Series from an unordered set:

```py
val_1 = {num_samples, " ",num_classes, " ",1}
row_1 = pd.Series(val_1)
```

Instead, use a list:

```py
val_1 = [num_samples, " ",num_classes, " ",1]
row_1 = pd.Series(val_1)
```